# Thermal reliefs for via-in-pad under BGA?

Tags: soldering, high-speed, via, manufacturing, bga

I'm doing the layout of a high-speed (Multi gigabit) system based on an FPGA with more than a thousand BGA pads and 0.8mm pitch on a 10-layer board. I'm using via in pads that will be copper-filled and capped.

My question is:

For such specs, is it required to add thermal reliefs to GND/PWR vias under the BGAs?

I've never added thermal reliefs for normal vias before and didn't face any manufacturing issues. Not sure if this applies to the current system or not.

Comment: I think this would be a good question for your assembly house(s), as they're going to have to reliably assemble the product. My guess is that no thermal relief is okay for inner layers only but that and $3 will get you a coffee.

Comment: On a 1000-pin BGA it's very common that there's not enough room between vias to use thermal relief.The only authoritative answer is your assembly house, but I've never seen it used in this scenario.

Comment: I thought thermal relief wasn't an issue for reflow since everything gets equally hot so nothing is a heatsink?

Comment: I haven't thermal relieved anything other than through hole pads in quite a while.

Comment: @Spehro, that's a good idea, thanks! I'll contact the assembly house

Comment: I'm just concerned of adding reliefs because this increases inductance and also make cuts in reference plane which causes impedance mismatches